# Why my Jtextfield and jmenubar doesnt work

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Q1: MY JTextFeild and JMenuBar does not show up, and I don't know why 
there is an picture of the program.

Q2: I have seen a lot of ways to write a program of interface, I don't know which way is better. Is this way or this way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=706Ye4ubtEY

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JTextField; 
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public  class Real_Interface extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public Real_Interface(){
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.add(new JLabel("Rocket Data Visualization Tool"));
        window.setTitle("Rocket Data Visualization Tool");
        window.setSize(640, 480);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);

        JTextField tf = new JTextField(); 
        tf.setText("New Text");
        String str = tf.getText();
        tf.setVisible(true);

        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("haha");
        JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("haha2");
        file.add(menuItem);
        file.addSeparator();
        file.add(menuItem2);
        bar.add(file);


        JButton button = new JButton("OK");  
        window.add(button);  
        button.setBounds(250, 400, 150, 40);  
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Real_Interface();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("The Button Works!");
        Plot.main(null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few reasons

The menubar has not been assigned to the frame

```
window.setJMenuBar(bar);
```

The textfield has not been added

```
window.add(textfield, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

This component is visible by default so calling `setVisible` is unnecessary.

The frame needs to be made visible after all components have been added to the frame rather than beforehand

```
window.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `JTextField tf` and `JMenuBar bar` aren't added to their parent (the `window` ?).